# unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: did not find expected key on line "advanced" field

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

The build is throwing error:- did not find the expected key on line "advanced" field
Below is the yaml file snipped that i have written

````
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}-sqs
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  minReplicaCount: {{ .Values.hpa.minReplicaCount }}
  maxReplicaCount: {{ .Values.hpa.maxReplicaCount }}
  fallback:
    failureThreshold: 3
    replicas: {{ .Values.hpa.minReplicaCount }}
  advanced:
    behavior:
      scaleDown:
        stabilizationWindowSeconds: {{ .Values.hpa.scaleDown.stabilizationWindowSeconds}} 
        policies:
{{ toYaml .Values.hpa.scaleDown.policies | indent 6 }}
      scaleUp:
        stabilizationWindowSeconds: {{ .Values.hpa.scaleUp.stabilizationWindowSeconds}}  
        policies:
{{ toYaml .Values.hpa.scaleUp.policies | indent 6 }}
        selectPolicy: {{ .Values.hpa.selectPolicyForScaleUp}} ```
````

Comment: One thing you can check is the `indent 6`, it seems it should be `indent 10` (or `indent 8`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some formatting and indentation issues in the yaml file you have provided as said by `Rafał Leszko`.  You can use **[helm lint](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_lint/)** for validating your charts before deploying them. Helm Linter will validate your chart syntax and pints out all the errors, warnings and info which will break your code from working.(Source: Helm docs)

Comment: @AbhishekKhaiwale is your issue resolved, revert back if you need any help. Upvote or accept this as it might help remaining community members.